# How can I get rid off the warnings message while I use the time magic scripts with Xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost

While I use the magic time scripts with Xgboost, there are always a lot of warnings that co-existed. Could anyone tell me how should I rewrite the codes and get rid of these messages?

```
%%time

bst_cv1 = xgb.cv(xgb_params, dtrain, num_boost_round=50, nfold=3, seed=0, 
                feval=xg_eval_mae, maximize=False, early_stopping_rounds=10)

print ('CV score:', bst_cv1.iloc[-1,:]['test-mae-mean'])
```

herein are the warnings:

```
[19:57:20] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:188: reg:linear is now deprecated in favor of reg:squarederror.
[19:57:20] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/learner.cc:576: 
Parameters: { "silent" } might not be used.

  This could be a false alarm, with some parameters getting used by language bindings but
  then being mistakenly passed down to XGBoost core, or some parameter actually being used
  but getting flagged wrongly here. Please open an issue if you find any such cases.


[19:57:21] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:188: reg:linear is now deprecated in favor of reg:squarederror.
[19:57:21] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/learner.cc:576: 
Parameters: { "silent" } might not be used.

  This could be a false alarm, with some parameters getting used by language bindings but
  then being mistakenly passed down to XGBoost core, or some parameter actually being used
  but getting flagged wrongly here. Please open an issue if you find any such cases.


[19:57:21] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/objective/regression_obj.cu:188: reg:linear is now deprecated in favor of reg:squarederror.
[19:57:21] WARNING: C:/Users/Administrator/workspace/xgboost-win64_release_1.5.1/src/learner.cc:576: 
Parameters: { "silent" } might not be used.

  This could be a false alarm, with some parameters getting used by language bindings but
  then being mistakenly passed down to XGBoost core, or some parameter actually being used
  but getting flagged wrongly here. Please open an issue if you find any such cases.
```